# Script which searches for tables matching a pattern and then truncates them

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, shell

I want to create a script which searches for tables matching a pattern and then truncates them.

I have logged into mysql and ran the following which gives the correct tables:

```
SELECT concat('TRUNCATE TABLE `', TABLE_NAME, '`;') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'weather%';
```

However I am not sure how to embedd this into a shell script which would output the SQL like so:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `weather`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `weathermonth`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `weathermonthlp`;
```

and then execute the statements.

Thanks

Comment: you don't want to be parsing mysql output in a shell script. just write a stored procedure in mysql to do the select/truncating, then your shell script simply needs `mysql -u user -p pw -e 'call your_function();'`

Comment: the problem is that we dont want to write individual truncate statements, is it possible to use select concat to output the statements to be executed and then execute them in an sp?

Answer (score 1):

To run MySQL commands from the shell, you can pipe to the standard input of `mysql`, for example:

```
mysql << 'EOF'
SELECT concat('TRUNCATE TABLE `', TABLE_NAME, '`;') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'weather%';
EOF
```

Now, your MySQL commands produce further MySQL commands...
If you want to execute them, you could again pipe to `mysql`,
also using the `-s` flag to suppress non-query output produced by MySQL itself in the process, like this:

```
mysql -s << 'EOF' | mysql
SELECT concat('TRUNCATE TABLE `', TABLE_NAME, '`;') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'weather%';
EOF
```

Note that `<< 'EOF'` is a *here-document* whose content is taken literally, so that you don't need to escape any special characters in the MySQL commands.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with something like this, and add more code if needed, for exmaple the database parameter. Also be sure to use quotes when invoking search with spaces.

./truncate.sh "some search with spaces if its even possible to have space in table name"

```
#!/bin/bash
searchpattern="$1"

table_list=$(mysql -BN -e "SELECT CONCAT(TABLE_SCHEMA,'.', TABLE_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '$searchpattern%';")
echo $table_list;
IFS=" "

while read i; do

    echo "TRUNCATE TABLE $i;"

done < <(echo $table_list)
```

that script should output the sql, but you need to verify it before running